# Best way to add content of a word doc to another in powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word, data-conversion

I'm working on a project where I need to search through hundreds of word documents for a list of strings that are in the title and add the contents of those documents to a new word file. It's not just text but charts and drawings too. I have the following but it keeps corrupting the word doc. I was thinking about trying to convert to another format like xml and add that to a word doc but wasn't sure if that would work.

```
$list = Get-Content O:\Users\me\Downloads\list.txt
Foreach ($obj in $list) {
$nxt = Get-ChildItem -Path O:\Users\me\Downloads -Recurse -Filter "*$obj*"
Add-Content -Path O:\Users\me\Downloads\PowerShell.docx -Value $nxt}
```

Comment: `$list = get-content C:\pa\th\to\file; $list > newfile.txt`

Comment: Word documents aren't simple text files, so Add-Content will do you no good..

Comment: Can you give me a recommendation on what would work? I can try to convert the word docs to something else. Keeping in mind I need the drawings and stuff too.

Comment: @snowman, have you looked at accessing the MS Word COM Object? Googling ['Word COMObject Powershell'](https://www.google.com/search?q=word+comobject+powershell) and taking a look at the [VBA API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application) should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Combining Word documents into one can result in a lot of problems that you might need to avoid - e.g. loss of layout, loss of formatting, loss of numbering, references to data items such as bookmarks and document properties and so on. Perhaps best to convert each document to PDF and combine those instead. You can do the conversion via the Word object model but you would need to look to other toold for the combination.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I ended up breaking it up into 2 steps. I used Powershell to gather all the word docs together and took the cowards way out by using a VBA script in Word to merge everything together.